# Can I pass JSX to value property with TextField component from MUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Can I pass JSX/html to the `value` property with `TextField` component from MUI?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const message = "Hello World";
  const [commentText, setCommentText] = useState(message);
  const comment = { editedText: true };

  const messageEdited = `${commentText}${
    comment.editedText ? " (Edited)" : ""
  }`;

  return (
    <Box component="form" noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField
        id="outlined-basic"
        label="Outlined"
        variant="outlined"
        value={messageEdited}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Instead of having `messageEdited` like this

```
  const messageEdited = `${commentText}${
    comment.editedText ? " (Edited)" : ""
  }`;
```

Can I do something like this?

```
  const messageEdited = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <div>commentText</div>
        <span>(edited)</span>
      </>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Box component="form" noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField
        id="outlined-basic"
        label="Outlined"
        variant="outlined"
        value={messageEdited()}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Passing the `messageEdited` function to the `value` property displays `[object Object]` inside the text input.

The doc says the `value` property takes any so wonder if I can do it.
https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/

#### Attempts

```
  const renderMessage = () => {
    return [
      <div key={comment._id}>{comment.text}</div>,
      <span key={comment._id}>(edited)</span>,
    ];
  };

  return (
    <Box component="form" noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField
        id="outlined-basic"
        label="Outlined"
        variant="outlined"
        value={messageEdited()}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you do it you will get an error

```
Invalid value for prop `value` on <input> tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM. For details, see https://reactjs.org/link/attribute-behavior
```

What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source code and:

1. `value` is passed down to `Input` [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/6fd17fc75ad5ebcfc37d04a515e39ff15bb4cda4/packages/mui-material/src/TextField/TextField.js#L165)
2. down to `InputBase` [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/6fd17fc75ad5ebcfc37d04a515e39ff15bb4cda4/packages/mui-material/src/Input/Input.js#L146)
3. and to `input` element [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/6fd17fc75ad5ebcfc37d04a515e39ff15bb4cda4/packages/mui-material/src/InputBase/InputBase.js#L131)

`input` element automatically converts everything to string, so maybe this component can take anything, but in normal text input mode it will always return everything to string